# ImageMagick can run on Windows PowerShell but can't run with go

Tags: powershell, go, cmd, imagemagick, watermark

I need to add watermark with ImageMagick, for some reason, I need to run it with golang.

Here is my code snippet

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    currentDir, _ := os.Getwd()

    sourceImg := os.Args[1]

    sourceName := filepath.Base(sourceImg)
    sourceExt := filepath.Ext(sourceImg)
    imgNameWithoutExt := strings.Replace(sourceName, sourceExt, "", 1)
    targetImgName := imgNameWithoutExt + "_wm" + sourceExt
    targetImg := filepath.Join(filepath.Dir(sourceImg), targetImgName)

    command := "bash"
    secondParam := "-c"
    // In macOS or Linux, use backslash to escape parenthesis
    cmdStr := `magick "` + sourceImg + `" -set option:watermarkWidth "%[fx:int(w*0.25)]" -alpha set -background none \\( -fill "#FFFFFF80" -stroke "#FF000080" -strokeWidth 3 -undercolor "#FF000080" -font "arial.ttf" -size "%[watermarkWidth]x" label:"This is watermark" -gravity center -geometry +10+10 -rotate -30 \\) -composite -quality 40 "` + targetImg + `"`

    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        sourceImg = strings.ReplaceAll(sourceImg, "\\", "\\\\")
        targetImg = strings.ReplaceAll(targetImg, "\\", "\\\\")
        // In PowerShell, use babckstick (`) to escape parenthesis
        command = "cmd"
        secondParam = "/c"
        cmdStr = `magick "` + sourceImg + `" -set option:watermarkWidth "%[fx:int(w*0.25)]" -alpha set -background none ` + "`(" + ` -fill "#FFFFFF80" -stroke "#FF000080" -strokeWidth 3 -undercolor "#FF000080" -font "arial.ttf" -size "%[watermarkWidth]x" label:"This is watermark" -gravity center -geometry +10+10 -rotate -30 ` + "`)" + ` -composite -quality 40 "` + targetImg + `"`
    }

    fmt.Println(cmdStr)

    cmd := exec.Command(command, secondParam, cmdStr)
    cmd.Dir = currentDir
    ouput, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", ouput, err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Watermark was successfully added!")
    }
}
```

Because I've use `os.Getwd()` in the code, so we cannot run it directly through `go run main.go`, instead, we should build an executable

```sh
# build Windows executable
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-w -s" -o "test-magick.exe" main.go

# build macOS executable
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-w -s" -o "test-magick" main.go

# build Linux executable(I didn't test)
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-w -s" -o "test-magick" main.go
```

On macOS, the executable works fine, the watermark was successfully added
[image]

On Windows(in PowerShell), it returns an error, actually no specified error message, it just failed
[image]

Anyone who knows how to solve this error?

Comment: It is simpler to execute  the command directly instead of executing  a shell to execute the command. The direct path eliminates the need for shell escaping.

Comment: Thats not how os.exec works. each argument is its own argument. Duplicate.

Comment: @Volker But on macOS, it works

Comment: As an aside: on command lines parsed by executables on Windows, including by PowerShell, ``\`` only serves as the escape character before `"`, not also before before other characters. Therefore, there is no need to escape ``\`` as ``\\`` in file-system paths,

Comment: @mklement0 Actually, I tried to comment this two line `sourceImg = strings.ReplaceAll(sourceImg, "\\", "\\\\")` and `targetImg = strings.ReplaceAll(targetImg, "\\", "\\\\")`, but the result is the same, failed.

Comment: My comment was _an aside_, because (a) accidentally doubling ``\\`` in file-system paths is _tolerated_  but (b), more importantly, the real source of your problem is that _you're not calling PowerShell_, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're *not* using *PowerShell* to invoke your executable from inside your Go application**, you're using `cmd.exe`, which has different syntax rules (it doesn't recognize `` ` `` (the backtick) as the escape character, `%` is a metacharacter, no support for escaping `"` as `\"`, ...)

Therefore, because you're mistakenly passing a command line designed for `powershell.exe` (the Windows PowerShell CLI) to `cmd.exe`, the legacy Windows shell, which fails, due to the syntax differences.

Therefore, replace:

```
    command = "cmd"
    secondParam = "/c"
```

with:

```
    command = "powershell.exe"
    secondParam = "-c"
```

Additionally, consider placing the following arguments before `-c`, for added robustness:

```
   "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-NoProfile"
```

See the [documentation for `powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe).

---

Taking a step back:

**Your executable call doesn't use any *shell features*** (such as redirecting to a file, connecting multiple commands via a pipeline, ...), so **you could simply invoke `magick` *directly*, with it and all its arguments passed *individually*** to `exec.Command()`, which speeds up the operation and avoids the need for escaping.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I've tried run it in cmd(not PowerShell) and invoke `magick` directly, but the result is the same, failed, see in my update.

Comment: @Willis, it doesn't matter what shell you run your Go program from, what matters is what shell you're using in your `exec.Command()` call, and you're mistakenly calling `cmd.exe` instead of `powershell.exe`, as explained in the answer. But, as stated, you should consider not calling via a shell at all, and execute `magic` directly.

Comment: @Willis, see if my update helps.

Comment: In your update you are not constructing parameters directly you are making a string and then splitting it, anything can happen. In particular most quoting is preserved when it shouldn't be there.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, I just tried use powershell.exe `cmd := exec.Command("powershell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-NoProfile", "-c", cmdStr)`, it works, but I don't understand, it that cmd.exe cannot do this? I think if I can run it directly in cmd Window, it should be can run it through golang executable in cmd Window.

Comment: @xenoid, I think Willis created confusion by changing the code in the question after the fact. I've reverted the question to the original form, which my answer is based on: `cmdStr` is a single string containing a PowerShell command line that is properly passed as a single argument to the `-c` parameter of `powershell.exe`

Comment: @Willis, no you cannot pass a command line (a piece of source code) designed _for PowerShell_ to `cmd.exe`, because these two shells are fundamentally different, both in terms of syntax and built-in commands. Once your Go program is compiled, it doesn't matter what shell you call _it_ from (assuming you fulfill the syntax requirements of the running shell for _that_ invocation), because your Go program invariably uses `powershell.exe` _internally_

Comment: @mklement0 But what if I use `cmd.exe` as the first param of `exec.Command()`? Like this: `cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/c", cmdStr)`, is the go executable will still invoke `powershell.exe` internally?

Comment: @Willis: `cmd.exe` and PowerShell are unrelated. If you want to execute (Windows) PowerShell code, you need `powershell.exe`. But, to go back to basics, your particular executable call needs _neither_ `cmd.exe` nor `powershell.exe` - using `magick` as the first `exec.Command()` argument, with all pass-through arguments  specified individually, should do.